# Multiselect picklist right section not getting prepopulated values using lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-duallistbox

Created Quick action and attached that lightning component with this Quick action. Alert message showing the result which is coming from the controller soql but right section is showing empty.

```
public class ShoppingController {

@AuraEnabled
public static List<OnlineMarket__c> olRecordId(String recordId){
    List<OnlineMarket__c> pList = new List<OnlineMarket__c>();
    if(recordId != null){
        pList = [Select Shop_Product__c From OnlineMarket__c Where ID =: recordId Limit 1];
    }
    return pList;
 }
}
```

---

---

```
<aura:component controller="ShoppingController" 
                implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,
                flexipage:availableForRecordHome,
                force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >


<aura:attribute name="ListOfOption" type="Object[]" default="[{'label':'Amazon','value':'Amazon'},
                                                             {'label':'Flipkart','value':'FlipKart'},
                                                            {'label':'Myntra','value':'Myntra'}]">
</aura:attribute>


<aura:attribute name="defaultOptions" type="List" />
<aura:attribute name="defaultOptions" type="List" />
<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String"/>

<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

<lightning:dualListbox aura:id="selectOptions" name="Shopping Site"  label="Shopping Site" 
                   sourceLabel="Available data" 
                   selectedLabel="Chosen data" 
                   options="{!v.ListOfOption}" 
                   value="{!v.defaultOptions}"

                   />

</aura:component>
```

---

---

```
  ({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    var action = component.get('c.olRecordId');
    action.setParams({ recordId : component.get("v.recordId") });
    
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(response.getReturnValue()));
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            component.set("v.defaultOptions",response.getReturnValue());
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
  },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The `values` attribute takes a list of `string` values as input but in your code, the value returned is JSON representation of an `sObject`. You will need to process the response and take out the value of `Shop_Product__c` from each record.

```
if (state === 'SUCCESS') {
  let values = response.getReturnValue().map(item => {
    return item.Shop_Product__c;
  });
  component.set('v.defaultOptions', values);
}
```